# Matrix product, prove/calculate individual row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove a row of a matrix product is the product of a row and a matrix: $\left( AC \right) _{j} = A_{j}C
$. I know the result, not the intermediate steps. Assuming $A,C$ are respectively $m \times n$ and $n \times p$, this is my attempt:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(AC\right)_{j}
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ji}C_{i1},\dots,\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ji}C_{ip}\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ji}(C_{i1},\dots,C_{ip}) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ji}C_{i} \\
&=A_{j}C \\
&=A_{j}C
\end{align}
$$

I'm not comfortable with the summation algebra and don't understand how this step can be correct:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(AC\right)_{j}
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ji}C_{i} \\
&=A_{j}C
\end{align}
$$

Thus I'm not sure I used the correct way. Can someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :** there is a neat way to handle these issues by considering the canonical basis $e_k^T=(0,0,... 0,1,0 ...0), k=1...n$ where the $1$ occupies the $k$th position.

Using these vectors, we can operate row (resp. column) extraction by left- (resp. right-) multiplying by $e_k^T$, (resp. $e_k$) :

$$\begin{cases}e_i^TM&=&i\text{th row of } M\\
Me_j&=&j\text{th column of } M\\
\end{cases}$$

Now, your issue boils down *very simply* to the fact that the $i$th row of $AB$ can be written in two ways

$$e_i^T(AB)=(e_i^TA)B$$

---

I had a first answer, that I have found much less satisfying than the version above ; I have erased it.

Comment: Is the method used in my question a dead-end?

Comment: No, I find it correct but the "black bullets" you use aren't a very "canonical" way to write such things. Please have a look at my complete re-writing of my answer.

Comment: Thanks. So my understanding is you propose another way to prove the assertion (which I find elegant), and mine was correct though much longer and complex. I removed the unusual bullets in indexing (they seem to be used only in statistics to deal with sample means), and now it looks like my method ends with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ji}C_{i}=A_{j}C$, i.e. replacing a dot product of a vector of scalars and a vector of columns (which is a linear combination of the columns) by a matrix product involving a row-vector and a matrix. This last step is meaningful.